# Code Golf: Spider webs

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf, rosetta-stone

### The challenge

The shortest code by character count to output a spider web with rings equal to user's input.

A spider web is started by reconstructing the center ring:

```
   \_|_/
  _/   \_
   \___/
   / | \
```

Then adding rings equal to the amount entered by the user. A ring is another level of a "spider circles" made from `\ / |` and `_`, and wraps the center circle.

Input is always guaranteed to be a single positive integer.

### Test cases

```
Input
    1
Output
      \__|__/
      /\_|_/\
    _/_/   \_\_
     \ \___/ /
      \/_|_\/
      /  |  \
```

---

```
Input
    4
Output
         \_____|_____/
         /\____|____/\
        / /\___|___/\ \
       / / /\__|__/\ \ \
      / / / /\_|_/\ \ \ \
    _/_/_/_/_/   \_\_\_\_\_
     \ \ \ \ \___/ / / / / 
      \ \ \ \/_|_\/ / / /
       \ \ \/__|__\/ / /
        \ \/___|___\/ /
         \/____|____\/
         /     |     \
```

---

```
Input:
    7
Output:
            \________|________/
            /\_______|_______/\
           / /\______|______/\ \
          / / /\_____|_____/\ \ \
         / / / /\____|____/\ \ \ \
        / / / / /\___|___/\ \ \ \ \
       / / / / / /\__|__/\ \ \ \ \ \
      / / / / / / /\_|_/\ \ \ \ \ \ \
    _/_/_/_/_/_/_/_/   \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_
     \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \___/ / / / / / / /
      \ \ \ \ \ \ \/_|_\/ / / / / / /
       \ \ \ \ \ \/__|__\/ / / / / /
        \ \ \ \ \/___|___\/ / / / /
         \ \ \ \/____|____\/ / / /
          \ \ \/_____|_____\/ / /
           \ \/______|______\/ /
            \/_______|_______\/
            /        |        \
```

Code count includes input/output (i.e full program).

Comment: Happy Halloween!

Comment: Awesome.  =]  Stupid character limit.

Comment: Positive *and* greater than zero? Isn't that a bit superfluous? :)

Comment: @Joren: Brought to you by the Department of Redundancy Department.

Comment: Is it OK to use `argv` or similar for the input?

Comment: @Kinopiko: Yes, see older golf questions.

Comment: @Chris - The only thing worse than redundancy jokes are recursion jokes.

Comment: @Chris - A man walks into a bar to tell a joke about a man who walks into a bar...

Comment: Once upon a time, there were code golf challenges that didn't involve ASCII art!  I guess that's just a fairy tale now.  ;-)

Comment: Not really, check out mine :)

Comment: @Ken: Number crunching golfs are boring ;)

Comment: @Ken: Check mine out, then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230978/code-golf-four-is-magic

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Golfscript - 124 chars

All whitespace is significant! If you accidently add a newline to the end there will be an extra `_` at the end of the output

```
~):@,{@\:&-:0' ': *& '/':/+*'\\':~'_':
0*.'|':|\/~ +&*n}%
/+@*   ~
+@*n ~+@*


@/ +*n@,{):& *@&-:( ~+*/[
 ](!=&*.|\~/ +(*n}%
```

**Golfscript - 129 chars**

```
~):@,{@\:&-:0' ': *&' /'*'\\':~'_':
0*.'|'\'/'~ +&*n}%'_/'@*   '\_'@*n ~+@*


@'/ '*n@,{):& *@&-:( ~+*'/'[
 ](!=&*.'|'\~'/ '(*n}%
```

**Golfscript - 133 chars**

```
~):@,{@\:&-:0' ': *&' /'*'\\':~'_':
0*.'|'\'/'~ +&*n}%'_/'@*3 *'\_'@*n' \\'@*3
*@'/ '*n@,{):& *@&-:( ~+*'/''_ '1/(!=&*.'|'\~'/ '(*n}%
```

Comment: Only have to get rid of 63 more chars to beat this solution!

Comment: Only 47 chars to go now. Look out.

Comment: Drat, Perl loses by 37 characters. I tried removing every fourth character from my solution, but that made it stop printing out spider webs.

Comment: @mobrule, your solution had better presentation, for what it's worth :)

Answer (score 40):

### Perl, 164 chars

<strike>195</strike> <strike>184</strike> <strike>171</strike> <strike>167</strike> 164

```
print@o=((map{$z=_ x($x=1+$N-$_);$"x$x." /"x$_."\\$z|$z/".'\ 'x$_.$/}0..($N=<>)),
"_/"x++$N."   ".'\_'x$N.$/);
y'/\\'\/',@o||y#_# #,$t++||y#_ # _#,print while$_=pop@o
```

First statement prints out the top half of the spider web. Second statement uses transliteration operations to create a reflection of the top half.

This next one weighs in closer to 314 chars (of productive code), but is more in the spirit of the season.

```
           ;               "
         Tr                 Ic
        K|                   |t
       Re                     aT
       ",                     "H
       av                     e
        A:                    -
     )H AL                   LO  W
    ee  N"                   ,"  En
   jo    y_                 Yo    ur
   _      C&&             y";     ##
   &I      ();           $N=      1+
   <>;      $,=  $/;@O  =((     map 
    $" x($   X=$N-$_). ${   f}x$_.$
        B.${U}x$X.$P.${U}x$X.$
    F.${b}x$_,0..$N-1),${g}x$N.(${S}
   x3).${c}x$N);sub I{($F,$B,$U, $P)
  =qw         (/ \\ _ |);;         ${
 S}=        " ";$f=$S.$F;$g=$       U.
 $F     ;$b=$B.$S;$c=$B.${U};}@{    P}=
@{     O};  while($_=pop@{P}  ){     @{
 P}    ||   y:_: :;$spooky++  ||    0|
  0    ||   y@_ @ _@;y:/:8:;   ;    ;
   ;   ;;   y:\\:/:;y:8:\\:;  @O   =
    (  @O    ,$_);}print@O;   q{
       Do     !Discuss:Rel    ig
       io       n,Politi      cs
        ,&                   &T
        heG                 rea
          tP              ump
            ki           n}
```

Hat tip to http://www.ascii-art.de/ascii/s/spider.txt

I constructed the spider shaped code by hand, but see the [Acme::AsciiArtinator](http://search.cpan.org/~mob/Acme-AsciiArtinator-0.01/lib/Acme/AsciiArtinator.pm) module on CPAN for help with automating (or at least semi-automating) the task.

Comment: I think you may have too many of those alphabetical letters in there

Comment: (Kibbitzing) -2 by changing `"\\ "` to `'\ '` and similarly for `"\\_"`.

Comment: (More kibbitzing) Can change the first "print" to "warn" for -1. A bit dubious though.

Comment: Thanks KP. turns out you can also use `y'''` and get rid of one more `\\`

Comment: Actually I tried the `y'''`, and got an error message. I didn't notice that it was possible the way you did it.

Comment: `Trick || TreaT`, `Enjoy Your C&&y`, `Have A :-) HALLOWeeN`, `Do !Discuss: Religion, Politics, && The Great Pumpkin` am I missing anything else? :D

Answer (score 9):

### Python - 212 chars

```
n=input()+1;b,f,p,u,s='\/|_ '
a=[s*(n-i)+' /'*i+b+u*(n-i)+p+u*(n-i)+f+'\ '*i+s*(n-i)for
i in range(n)]
print"\n".join(a+['_/'*n+s*3+'\_'*n,' \\'*n+u*3+'/ '*n]+[x[::-1]for
x in a[:0:-1]]+[a[0][::-1].replace(u,s)])
```

Answer (score 5):

### Perl: 161 characters

Note that this code includes the starting web in the source.  (The doubled backslash at the end is a shame.  An earlier version didn't have that.)

```
$_='
 \_|_/
_/   \_
 \___/ 
 /_|_\\';
for$x(1..<>){
s|(.\S).*([/\\].)|$1$&$2|g;
s|\\(.*)/| \\_$1_/$` /$&\\ |;
s|(\s+)\K/(.*).$| \\$&/$1 /_$2_\\|
}
s|_(?=.*$)| |g;
print
```

The whitespace within `$_` is significant (of course), but none of the rest is.  If you have a minor suggestion that improves this, please feel free to just edit my code.  For example, [Kinopiko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181548/kinopiko) has nicely shaved off 6 characters!

Depending on how you count command-line switches, this might be shorter (154 by usual Perl golf rules if I can count correctly):

```
#!perl -ap
$_='
 \_|_/
_/   \_
 \___/ 
 /_|_\\';
s|(.\S).*([/\\].)|$1$&$2|g,
s|\S(.*).| \\_$1_/$` /$&\\ |,
s|(\s+)\K/(.*).$| \\$&/$1 /_$2_\\|while$F[0]--;
s|_(?=.*$)| |g
```

Comment: Change the second-to-last line from `1while s|_(.*\\\n)| $1|;` to `s/_(?=(.*)\s+$)/ /g;`

Comment: Make that `s/_(?=.*\s+$)/ /g;`.

Comment: +1 I considered trying something like this, but felt it would be too long. wow! well done

Answer (score 4):

## Vb.net, windows console, Infer, Strict, Explicit ON.

Microsoft word is saying **442 characters** without space

It might be possible to reduce it more but **this is my last update(*try #2*)**

```
Module z
Sub Main()
    Dim i = CInt(Console.ReadLine), j = i + 1, h = j * 2 + 1, w = h * 2, z = "_", b = " "

    For y = 0 To h
        For x = 0 To w
            Dim l = (x + y Mod 2 + i Mod 2) Mod 2, u = j + y, e = j - y, k = h + e, o = x = h Or x = h - 1
            Console.Write(If(x = h, If(y = j, b, If(y = j + 1, z, "|")), "") & If(x = w, vbLf, If(y = j, If(x Mod 2 = 0 = (x < h), If(o, b, z), If(x < h, "/", "\")), If(x < k And x > u Or (x < u And x > k Or o) And y < h, z, If(x = k Or (x < u And y < j And x > e Or x > u And y > j And x < w + e) And l = 0, "/", If(x = u Or (x > k And y < j And x < h + u Or x < k And y > j And x > y - j - 1) And l = 1, "\", b))))))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: finally went under 700 characters, vb will never win in this kind of game but was fun to do

Comment: after a rewrite, less than 500 characters :-)

Comment: a c# version would be less characters for sure, about 60 to 75 less characters

Answer (score 3):

## Python: 240 Characters

Nothing too tricky here; just printing line by line - <strike>298 280 271 266 265 261 260 254</strike> 240 characters (ignore the last 2 line breaks)

```
u,b,f,s,a='_\/ |'
m=input()+1
print'\n'.join([(m-x)*s+x*' /'+b+(m-x)*u+a+(m-x)*u+f+x*'\ 'for x in
  range(0,m)]+['_/'*m+s*3+'\_'*m+'\n'+(s+b)*m+u*3+'/ '*m]+[x*s+(m-x)*
  ' \\'+f+x*u+a+x*u+b+(m-x)*'/ 'for x in range(1,m)] + [s*m+f+s*m+a+s*m+b])
```

Comment: `u,b,f,s,a='_\/ |'` you don't need to double the backslash here

Comment: In Python 3 you would be able to simply say `p=print` (since in Py3k print is a function instead of a keyword). But `input` would have to be wrapped in `int`. Saves 5 chars.

Comment: `m=int(raw_input())+1` since you don't use `n` anywhere

Comment: Thank again, gnibbler - I used to use n - forgot that I didn't anymore.

Comment: @Stephan - Thanks! Yeah, I figured it was possible in py3k. I had tried it in 2.6 and it didn't work; no doubt keywords take precedence over functions. Why does input need to be wrapped in int? Has input changed behaviour in py3k?

Comment: `input` in P3 works like `raw_input`. Since this is P2, why do you have paren around `a` for the `print`?

Comment: @gnibbler - Haha - silly me. Yeah, I'm in 2.6 and am just getting used to the "best-practise" of treating print as a function rather than as a keyword. however, here at code golf, best-practise goes out the window ;-) Thanks! One more character!

Comment: Now we wait for the Perl/Ruby hackers to come along and blow us Python users out of the water...

Comment: Yes, but by the time the ruby/perl guys tee off the Python guys are at the 19th hole ;)

Comment: Actually Python's doing OK against Ruby, I posted a scoreboard as a second answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby1.9 - 181 chars

```
n=gets.to_i+1;s=' '
a=0.upto(n-1).map{|i|s*(j=n-i)+' /'*i+?\\+?_*j+'|'+?_*j+?/+'\ '*i+s*j}
d=a.reverse.map{|x|x.reverse};d[-1].tr!?_,s
puts a,'_/'*n+s*3+'\_'*n,' \\'*n+?_*3+'/ '*n,d
```

**Ruby1.8 - 185 chars**
Some improvements from JRL

```
n=gets.to_i+1;s=' '
u='_';a=0.upto(n-1).map{|i|s*(j=n-i)+' /'*i+'\\'+u*j+'|'+u*j+'/'+'\ '*i+s*j}
d=a.reverse.map{|x|x.reverse}
d[-1].tr!u,s;puts a,'_/'*n+s*3+'\_'*n,' \\'*n+u*3+'/ '*n,d
```

**Ruby - 207 chars**
Ruby seems to have some peculiar rules about the "\"

```
n=eval(gets)+1
b,f,p,u,s='\/|_ '.split""
a=0.upto(n-1).map{|i|s*(j=n-i)+' /'*i+b+u*j+"|"+u*j+f+"\\ "*i+s*j}
puts a,'_/'*n+s*3+'\_'*n,' \\'*n+u*3+'/ '*n,a[1..-1].reverse.map{
|x|x.reverse},a[0].reverse.tr(u,s)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby<sub>1.8</sub>, 179

Run with `ruby -n`

```
n=$_.to_i+1
u,s,c=%w{_ \  \ \\}
z=(1..n).map{|i|k=n-i
s*i+c*k+'/'+u*i+'|'+u*i+"\\"+'/ '*k+s*i}
y=z.reverse.map{|a|a.reverse}
z[-1].tr!u,s
puts y,'_/'*n+s*3+'\_'*n,c*n+u*3+'/ '*n,z
```

In the first attempt below it seemed like a good idea to just generate one quadrant (I chose lower left), and then mirror twice to get the whole web. But [gnibbler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174728/gnibbler) got better results generating both quadrants (of the top half) and then generating rather than patching up the inner area. So I revised mine to initially generate the other lower quadrant also, mirror only once, and also to leave the innermost row out of the mirror, which kind of converges with the other entry.

#### <strike>Ruby, 241</strike>

```
n=$_.to_i+1
m=2*n+1
u,s,b,f=%w{_ \  \\ /}
z=(0..n).map{|i|s*i+(s+b)*(n-i)+(i==0?u:f)+u*i}
q=z.reverse.map{|a|a.tr f+b,b+b+f}
q[n].gsub!' ','_'
q[n][m-1]=s
z=(q+z).map{|a|a+'|'+a.reverse.tr(f+b,b+b+f)}
z[n][m]=z[n+1][m]=s
z[m].gsub!u,s
puts z
```

Answer (score 3):

### Lua, 290

```
n=...s=string r=s.reverse g=s.gsub a="\\|/"j=(" /"):rep(n+1)..a..("\\ "):rep(n+1) k=j o=k
l=n*4+7 for i=1,n+1 do k=g(k,"^(.- )/(.-)|(.*)\\(.-)$","%1%2_|_%3%4")o=k..o end
o=o..r(o)print((g(g(g(g(r(g(o:sub(1,l),"_"," ")..o:sub(l+1)),j,g(j," ","_")),("."):rep(l),"%1\n"),a,"   "),r(a),"___")))
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 573 chars

Obviously it isn't even in the running w/regard to the character count.  The 573 number is just the file size on my windows machine, so that probably counts a few ctrl-M's. On the other hand, maybe 573 is under-counting it, since I incurred the wrath of the compiler by jettisoning all the #include's to save space, warnings be damned!

But hey, this is my first time attempting one of these, and it will undoubtedly be good practice to try to re-express it in something more compact.

```
#define B puts("");
#define K '\\'+'/'
#define F '_'+' '
#define P(s) putchar(s);
#define I int
c(I s,I f){if(s){P(f)c(s-1,f);P(f)}else P('|')} 
w(I lw,I s,I k,I f){if(s){P(' ')P(k)w(lw,s-1,k,f);P(K-k)P(' ')}else{P(K-k)c(1+lw,f);P(k)}}
h(I g,I s,I k,I f){I i;for(i=-1;i<g;++i)P(' ')w(g,s,k,f);} 
t(I g,I s){if(s)t(g+1,s-1);h(g,s,'/','_');B}
b(I g,I s){h(g,s,'\\',s?'_':' ');B;if(s)b(g+1,s-1);}
m(I s,I k,I f){if(s){P(f)P(k)m(s-1,k,f);P(K-k)P(f)}else{P(F-f)P(F-f)P(F-f)}}
main(I ac,char*av[]){I s;s=atoi(av[1]);t(0,s);m(1+s,'/','_');B;m(1+s,'\\',' ');B;b(0,s);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, <strike>340 - 309 - 269</strike> - 250 characters

Still room for improvement I think.

```
s=input()+1
f,b="/ ","\\"
r=range(s)
for i in r:w="_"*(s-i);print" "*(s+(i>=1)-i)+(f*i)[:-1]+b+w+"|"+w+"/"+"\ "*i
print"_/"*s+" "*3+"\_"*s+"\n"+" \\"*s+"_"*3+f*s
for i in r[::-1]:u="_ "[i<1]*(s-i);print" "*(s-i+(i>=1))+("\ "*i)[:-1]+"/"+u+"|"+u+b+f*i
```

-

### Python (alternative version), <strike>250</strike> - 246 characters

```
s=input()+1;r=range(s);c="/","\\";y="/ ","\\ "
def o(i,r):u="_ "[i<1 and r]*(s-i);print" "*(s+(i>=1)-i)+(y[r]*i)[:-1]+c[r<1]+u+"|"+u+c[r]+(y[r<1]*i)[:-1]
for i in r:o(i,0)
print"_/"*s+" "*3+"\_"*s+"\n"+" \\"*s+"_"*3+"/ "*s
for i in r[::-1]:o(i,1)
```

Comment: Could just use input() rather than int(raw_input()) - returns an int

Comment: Because Python treats strings as iterable, you should be able to simplify your assignment to c: `c='_ '`

Comment: (i>=1) beats (1,0)[i<1]. Can replace indentation with semicolons. Space after `print` not required.

Answer (score 1):

#### Python and Ruby just about even<sup>*</sup>

I would rather have continued the comment thread above that briefly mentioned Python vs Ruby, but I need formatting to do this. Smashery is certainly classy but doesn't need to worry: it turns out that Python and Ruby are in a pretty close race by one measure. I went back and compared Python to Ruby in the eight code-golf's that I have entered.

```
    Challenge       Best Python             Best Ruby

    The Wave          161                    99
    PEMDAS          no python entry       (default victory?)
    Seven Segs        160                   175
    Banknotes          83 (beat Perl!)       87  
    Beehive           144                   164
    RPN (no eval)     111 (157)              80 (107)
    Cubes             249                   233
    Webs              212                   181

    Victories           3                     4 (5?)
```

So the issue definitely isn't settled and got more interesting recently when gnibbler started entering on both sides. :-)

---

`*`<sub>I only counted fully functional entries.</sub>

Comment: My 249 char for Cubes in Python is fully functional, but there was a comment there that made it look like it was still broken, so Cubes is quite close. I'll have to do a Python entry for PEDMAS!

Comment: You should totally graph this data, DigitalRoss. Because of junk [code-golf] questions, may I suggest at least 10 votes for a statistical question?

Comment: Both of you: good points, please feel free to edit my CW stuff, I can think of no one more qualified than you two...

Comment: At a completely pointless metric, yes, they're even.  And both got spanked by Golfscript.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

### dc - 262

A "straightforward" solution in `dc` (OpenBSD). Not a contender, but it is always fun. Line breaks for "readability"

```
[lcP1-d0<A]sA?sN[lK32sclAxRlNlK-l1scd0!=ARl3PlKl0sclAxRl9PlKlAxRl4PlNlK-
l2scd0!=AAPR]sW95s0124s9[ /]s1[\\ ]s292s347s4lN[dsKlWx1-d0<L]dsLx
[\\_][   ][_/][lN[rdPr1-d0<L]dsLxRRPlNlLxRR]dsBxAP[/ ][_ _][ \\]lBxAP[ \\]s1
[/ ]s247s392s41[dsKlWx1+dlN>L]dsLx32s032s9lNsKlWx
```

sample output

```
$ dc web.dc  
3
   \___|___/
   /\__|__/\ 
  / /\_|_/\ \ 
_/_/_/   \_\_\_
 \ \ \_ _/ / / 
  \ \/_|_\/ / 
   \/__|__\/ 
   /       \
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 264 chars

shortened by in-lining the subroutines.

```
perl -E'$"="";($i=<>)++;@r=map{$p=$i-$_;@d=(" "x$_,(" ","\\")x$p,"/","_"x$_);($d="@d")=~y:\\/:/\\:;@d=reverse@d;$d.="|@d"}1..$i;say for reverse@r;$_=$r[0];y: _|:_  :;s:.(.*)\\.*/(.*).:$1_/   \\_$2:;say;y: _\\/:_ /\\:;say;$r[-1]=~y:_: :;say for grep{y:\\/:/\\:}@r;'
```

Expanded to improve readability.

```
perl -E'
  $"="";
  ($i=<>)++;
  @r=map{
    $p=$i-$_;
    @d=(
      " "x$_,
      (" ","\\")x$p,
      "/",
      "_"x$_
    );
    ($d="@d")=~y:\\/:/\\:;
    @d=reverse@d;
    $d.="|@d"
  }1..$i;
  say for reverse@r;
  $_=$r[0];
  y: _|:_  :;
  s:.(.*)\\.*/(.*).:$1_/   \\_$2:;
  say;
  y: _\\/:_ /\\:;
  say;
  $r[-1]=~y:_: :;
  say for grep{y:\\/:/\\:}@r;
'
```

This is the code before I minimized it:

```
#! /opt/perl/bin/perl
use 5.10.1;

($i=<>)++;
$"=""; #" # This is to remove the extra spaces for "@d"

sub d(){
  $p=$i-$_;
  " "x$_,(" ","\\")x$p,"/","_"x$_
}

sub D(){
 @d=d;
 ($d="@d")=~y:\\/:/\\:; # swap '\' for '/'
 @d=reverse@d;
 $d.="|@d"
}

@r = map{D}1..$i;

say for reverse@r; # print preceding lines

# this section prints the middle two lines
$_=$r[0];
y: _|:_  :;
s:.(.*)\\.*/(.*).:$1_/   \\_$2:;
say;
y: _\\/:_ /\\:;
say;

$r[-1]=~y:_: :; # remove '_' from last line
say for grep{y:\\/:/\\:}@r; # print following lines
```

Comment: Neither of the `sub` parts are necessary. Both of them are only called in one place, so they can be inlined into the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
(&)=(++) --9
f 0=[" \\_|_/","_/   \\_"," \\___/"," / | \\"] --52
f(n+1)=[s&h&u&"|"&u&g]&w(f n)&[s&g&s&"|"&s&h]where[a,b,c,d,e]=" _/\\|";[g,h]=["/","\\"];y=n+2;[u,s]=[r y b,r y a];p f s n x=let(a,b)=span(/=s)x in a&f b;i=dropWhile(==a);w[]=[];w[x]=[s&h&i(p(map(\x->if x==a then b else x))c d x)&g];w(l:e)|n==y*2-1=x%h:z|n>y=x&" "%" \\":z|n==y="_/"%"\\_":z|n<y=r(y-n)a&"\\ "%" /":z where n=length e;z=w e;x=r(n+1-y)a&g;(%)=(&).(&i l) --367
r=replicate --12
main=interact$unlines.f.read --29
```

Haskell entry weighing in at **469** characters.  I'm sure there is a lot of room for improvement.

good luck trying to read it :)

here is a more readable version.  Although there have been some changes since this version

```
spider 0=[" \\_|_/","_/   \\_"," \\___/"," / | \\"]
spider n=(s++"\\"++u++"|"++u++"/"):w m(spider(n-1))++[s++"/"++s++"|"++s++"\\"]
    where
        [a,b,c,d,e]=" _/\\|"
        [m,y]=[y*2,n+1]
        x=r y
        [u,s]=[x b,x a]
        t a b=map(\x->if x==a then b else x)
        p f s n x=let(a,b)=span(/=s)x;(c,d)=span(/=n)b in a++f c++d
        i=dropWhile(==a)
        w _[]=[]
        w _[x]=[s++"\\"++i(p(t a b)c d x)++"/"]
        w(a+1)(l:e) |a==m-1=wrapline x l"\\":z
                    |a>y=wrapline(x++" ")l" \\":z
                    |a==y=wrapline"_/"l"\\_":z
                    |a<y=wrapline(r(y-a)' '++"\\ ")l" /":z
            where
                z=w a e
                x=r(a+1-y)' '++"/"
                wrapline b l a=b++i l++a
r=replicate
main=interact$unlines.spider.read
```