# How does this integer encoding work?

Tags: language-agnostic, encoding, biginteger, mathematical-optimization

In [this code golf question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230978/code-golf-four-is-magic), there is a [python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230978/code-golf-four-is-magic/3231355#3231355) that encodes the lengths of all integers from 1 to 99 in english to a big number:

```
7886778663788677866389978897746775667552677566755267756675527886778663788677866355644553301220112001
```

To get the length of `n`, you just have to calculate `3 + (the_big_number / (10**n)) % 10`. How does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(the_big_number / (10^n)) % 10` pulls out the `n`th least significant digit of the big number,  so the lengths are just stored starting with the length of "zero" (1+3=4) at the far right, and following over to the length of "ninety-nine" (7+3=10) at the far left.

The shortest English numbers are three letters ("one", "two", "six", "ten"), so each length is stored with an offset of three.  The longest prior to 100 are 9 + 3 = 12 letters (e.g. "seventy-eight"), so each number can be stored as a single digit.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the right:

- the first digit is how many letters are in "zero" minus 3
- the second digit is how many letters are in "one", minus 3
- the third digit...
- ...the 100<sup>th</sup> digit is how many letters are in "ninety nine" minus three.

Note that that the longest number *"seventy seven"* has only 12 letters, which conveniently fits in a single digit after subtracting 3.